# Prisma findMany() - Ordering by count orders 0 count as positive infinity

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I am trying to findMany() users and orderBy their post count. I found exactly how to do it in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#sort-user-by-the-posts-count) and it works except it counts users with 0 posts as +infinity.  `orderBy: {posts: {count: asc}}`

For example, the ordering works in ascending starting with users with 1 post up until the users with a lot of posts, but the last users have 0 posts. Vice versa when descending.

I am using postgres as the provider, I really don’t know how to even google for this problem, and title this question. Please help.

```
model User {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts  Post[]        
}

model Post {
  id      Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  user    User  @relation(fields: [userID], references: [id])
  userID  Int        
}
```

```
  await prisma.user.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      posts: {
        count: 'desc',
      },
    },
  });
```

Output of a small test in descending order. You can see the post count is ordered 0 2 1 (in ascending order its output order is 1 2 0):

```
[
  { id: 3, _count: { posts: 0 } },
  { id: 1, _count: { posts: 2 } },
  { id: 2, _count: { posts: 1 } }
]
```

Comment: Could you please post your code here and your prisma model file as well

Comment: @FarrukhFaizy I've added a stripped down version, and i've tested to see the same problem persists